# Unable to remove date/time stamps on generated files

Tags: codefluent

I am unable to remove the date/time stamps from the generated files.

The problem is, when I'm editing the .cfp file, I'll set the Production Flags to "Overwrite, RemoveDates". But soon as I save the file, the Production Flags automatically get re-written as "Default, RemoveDates". This happens at both the Producer and Project Level.

If I use the projects advanced properties to set the flags through the GUI, than it sets the Productions Flags to "Default, RemoveDates". Also I don't have the same flag options as in the screenshot at

http://blog.codefluententities.com/2013/04/22/remove-the-current-date-and-time-to-generated-files/

The screenshot has the following checked:

1. Remove Diffs: Remove Dates
2. Remove Dates

None of my options match those in the screenshot. The only one that appears similar is:

1. Remove Diffs   <--- Note that the one in the screen shot has Remove Dates on the same line

Below is the model which was created using version/build 1.0.61214.805 of Codefluent Entities

```
<cf:project defaultNamespace="DemoRemoveDates" xmlns:cf="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/2005/1" xmlns:cfx="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/modeler/2008/1" xmlns:cfps="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/producers.sqlserver/2005/1" xmlns:cfom="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/producers.model/2005/1" xmlns:cfasp="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/producers.aspnet/2011/1" defaultConnectionString="Database=DemoRemoveDates;Server=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=true" defaultProducerProductionFlags="Default, RemoveDates" createDefaultMethodForms="true" createDefaultApplication="false" createDefaultHints="false">
  <cf:import path="Default.Surface.cfp" />
  <cf:producer enabled="false" productionFlags="None" name="SQL Server Producer" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer.SqlServerProducer, CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer">
    <cf:configuration connectionString="Database=DemoRemoveDates;Server=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=true" produceViews="true" targetVersion="Sql2008" targetDirectory="..\DemoRemoveDates.Persistence" cfx:targetProjectLayout="UpdateItems, DontRemove" cfx:targetProject="..\DemoRemoveDates.Persistence\DemoRemoveDates.Persistence.dbproj" />
  </cf:producer>
  <cf:producer productionFlags="None" name="BOM Producer" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.CodeDom.CodeDomProducer, CodeFluent.Producers.CodeDom, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1bb6d7cccf1045ec">
    <cf:configuration compileWithVisualStudio="true" targetDirectory="..\DemoRemoveDates" cfx:targetProject="..\DemoRemoveDates\DemoRemoveDates.csproj" cfx:targetProjectLayout="Update" />
  </cf:producer>
  <cf:producer enabled="false" productionFlags="None" name="ASP.NET WebForms Producer" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.UI.AspNetProducer, CodeFluent.Producers.UI">
    <cf:configuration categoryPath="UI\AspNetWebForms" targetDirectory="..\DemoRemoveDates.Web" cfx:targetProject="..\DemoRemoveDates.Web\DemoRemoveDates.Web.csproj" />
  </cf:producer>
  <cf:entity name="Contact" namespace="DemoRemoveDates" categoryPath="/DemoRemoveDates">
    <cf:property name="Id" key="true" />
    <cf:property name="Name" />
  </cf:entity>
</cf:project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article is pretty old. Try using this value instead:

```
productionFlags="Default, RemoveDates"
```

Or use the modeler to set this:

[image]

For the BOM producer, you need to set one more flag:

```
productionFlags="Default, Overwrite, RemoveDates"
```

You can also define it at model stage:

[image]

Comment: COMMENT 1 OF 2 - Still unable to get it to work. On the BOM Producer, as you suggested, I tried to set the productionFlags to "Default, Overwrite, RemoveDates"  by editing the CFP file. But when I save the file the productionFlags reverts back to "None".

Comment: COMMENT 2 OF 2 - Setting the defaultProducerProductionFlags at the project level is also acting quirky. For instance, I right clicked the project and selected "Overwrite" & "Remove Diffs" like you have in your screenshot. I then closed the project properties window and opened the .cfp file. "Overwrite" was NOT added to the .cfp file. I was than able to manualy add "Overwrite" and it kept the value when I saved the .cfp file. However, I then re-edited the .cfp by removing "Overwrite". When I save the file it re-added "Overwrite".

Comment: Always remember to unload you CodeFluent Entities project in Visual Studio when you edit the .cfp file directly (from a text editor).

Comment: Finally, I would recommand to use only the modeler OR only edit the XML file, not both.

Comment: Thanks, unloading & reloading was key to it working. Although it seems I also had to unload & reload after using the GUI to set the defaultProducerProductionFlags at the project level. I also deleted the entire phrase productionFlags="None" at the Producer Level (by entire I mean the name of the flag, the equal sign and the word "None").

Comment: @dave - never 'edit' the XML/CFP from Visual Studio while the project is loaded in any instance of Visual Studio. This works sometimes but not for all the XML elements/attributes, it's more generally unsupported. Also even if you open it from Visual Studio w/o changing it, you should close it before doing any 'Save All' type of action.